# SSL: Server key length and browser connection info. Base understanding

Tags: ssl, encryption

I'd like to understand something.

I generate keys with xca, which is a UI to openssl.

I have created a CA, then generate a server certificate for https and use this CA to sign the generated certificate. The newly created certs are subcerts of the CA (as far as I can tell).
I put in the CN for the domain, generate a new private key of **4096bit** length, export the crt and key pem including private key. Upload and configure nginx in this case.

Now I'm accessing the site over https. When clicking connection info in Firefox I see:

Connection Encrypted: High-grade Encryption (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, **128 bit keys**)

In Chromium:

Your connection to domain.tld is encrypted with **128-bit** encryption. <...>

The question/s:

My private key is 4096 bits. Why does it use 128 bits?

Which of the 4096 bits are used in those 128 bits?

Why am I generating a 4096 bit key if only 1/32 of its length are used?

I'd like to understand how this process works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4096 bit RSA key and its associated certificate provides authentication during the setup of the connection and key agreement, allowing the client to verify that they are indeed connected to your server, and not a man-in-the-middle claiming to be your server.

However, the RSA algorithm is orders of magnitude slower than symmetric algorithms like AES with similar security properties, as well as being limited in the amount of data it can encrypt. It is therefore not used to protect the actual data transmitted, and instead a session key for a symmetric algorithm is agreed between the client and server.

In this case, the session key is agreed using the ephemeral [Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie-Hellman) (ECDHE) algorithm, which allows client and server to derive a random, shared key without ever transmitting the key itself. It is *this* key which is 128bit, and is being used with the symmetric AES encryption algorithm in [Galois/Counter Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) (GCM).